# NetworkManager fails to connect with a cloned MAC address

Tags: networking, networkmanager, dhcp, ifconfig, mac-address

I need to spoof a specific MAC address to be able to connect to the local ethernet. So I filled in the "Cloned MAC address" field in `nm-connection-editor`. After this, `nm-applet` shows a spinning icon for several seconds, then falls back to an unwanted slower WiFi network, showing the typical signal strength icon. Then, after ≈20 seconds, the spinning icon reappears for several seconds (the context menu shows it's trying to connect to ethernet again), and finally NM falls back to the Wi-Fi. And so on, indefinitely (it seems).

The syslog shows these messages for each iteration of the above process (I removed date, hostname, timestamps and PIDs for brevity):

```
13:01:39 NetworkManager: <info>  device (enp0s31f6): carrier: link connected
13:01:39 NetworkManager: <info>  device (enp0s31f6): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
13:01:39 NetworkManager: <info>  policy: auto-activating connection 'Wired connection 1'
13:01:39 kernel: e1000e: enp0s31f6 NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
13:01:39 kernel: e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 enp0s31f6: 10/100 speed: disabling TSO
13:01:39 NetworkManager: <info>  device (enp0s31f6): Activation: starting connection 'Wired connection 1' (496467b0-8f31-3e42-abc2-6fb5da3e1df9)
13:01:39 NetworkManager: <info>  device (enp0s31f6): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
13:01:39 NetworkManager: <info>  device (enp0s31f6): set-hw-addr: set-cloned MAC address to 70:5A:B6:AE:87:48 (70:5A:B6:AE:87:48)
13:01:39 kernel: e1000e: enp0s31f6 NIC Link is Down
13:01:39 NetworkManager: <info>  device (enp0s31f6): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
13:01:39 NetworkManager: <info>  device (enp0s31f6): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
13:01:39 NetworkManager: <info>  dhcp4 (enp0s31f6): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
13:01:39 NetworkManager: <info>  dhcp4 (enp0s31f6): dhclient started with pid 5672
13:01:39 kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s31f6: link is not ready
13:01:39 kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s31f6: link is not ready
13:01:39 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s31f6 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x65ef8476)
13:01:42 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s31f6 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 5 (xid=0x65ef8476)
13:01:45 NetworkManager: <info>  device (enp0s31f6): state change: ip-config -> unavailable (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
13:01:45 NetworkManager: <info>  dhcp4 (enp0s31f6): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 5672
13:01:45 NetworkManager: <info>  dhcp4 (enp0s31f6): state changed unknown -> done
13:01:45 NetworkManager: <info>  device (enp0s31f6): set-hw-addr: reset MAC address to C8:F7:50:04:FF:DD (deactivate)
13:01:45 kernel: e1000e: enp0s31f6 NIC Link is Down
```

Now, the strange thing is I can make it work by running:

```
# ifconfig enp0s31f6 down
# ifconfig enp0s31f6 hw ether 70:5A:B6:AE:87:48
# ifconfig enp0s31f6 up
```

after which I wait for the spinning icon again and it connects for good, with these messages in syslog (removed avahi-daemon lines which now show up):

```
13:05:15 NetworkManager: <info>  device (enp0s31f6): carrier: link connected
13:05:15 NetworkManager: <info>  device (enp0s31f6): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
13:05:15 NetworkManager: <info>  policy: auto-activating connection 'Wired connection 1'
13:05:15 kernel: e1000e: enp0s31f6 NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
13:05:15 kernel: e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 enp0s31f6: 10/100 speed: disabling TSO
13:05:15 NetworkManager: <info>  device (enp0s31f6): Activation: starting connection 'Wired connection 1' (496467b0-8f31-3e42-abc2-6fb5da3e1df9)
13:05:15 NetworkManager: <info>  device (enp0s31f6): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
13:05:15 NetworkManager: <info>  device (enp0s31f6): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
13:05:15 NetworkManager: <info>  device (enp0s31f6): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
13:05:15 NetworkManager: <info>  dhcp4 (enp0s31f6): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
13:05:15 NetworkManager: <info>  dhcp4 (enp0s31f6): dhclient started with pid 5829
13:05:15 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s31f6 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0xf4fa910d)
13:05:18 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s31f6 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 6 (xid=0xf4fa910d)
13:05:18 dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 10.12.3.100 on enp0s31f6 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0xd91faf4)
13:05:18 dhclient: DHCPOFFER of 10.12.3.100 from 10.12.0.1
13:05:18 dhclient: DHCPACK of 10.12.3.100 from 10.12.0.1
13:05:18 NetworkManager: <info>  dhcp4 (enp0s31f6):   address 10.12.3.100
(snip other dhcp4 parameters)
13:05:18 NetworkManager: <info>  dhcp4 (enp0s31f6): state changed unknown -> bound
13:05:18 NetworkManager: <info>  device (enp0s31f6): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
13:05:18 NetworkManager: <info>  device (enp0s31f6): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
13:05:18 NetworkManager: <info>  device (enp0s31f6): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
13:05:18 NetworkManager: <info>  device (enp0s31f6): Activation: successful, device activated.
```

Any ideas to have NetworkManager successfully connect on its own?

EDIT: Following @thaller's advice in comments, here is the syslog at TRACE level of verbosity (because of the post size limit, I shortened messages that seemed irrelevant, you may spot them by `X`):

```
=== Around this time nm-applet starts displaying a spinning icon instead of the Wifi signal strength
time 11:32:14
<trace> platform-linux: event-notification: RTM_NEWLINK, flags 0, seq 0: 2: enp0s31f6 <UP,LOWER_UP;broadcast,multicast,up,running,lowerup> mtu 1500 arp 1 ethernet? not-init addrgenmode eui64 addr C8:F7:50:04:FF:DD rx:0,0 tx:0,0
<debug> platform: signal: link changed: 2: enp0s31f6 <UP,LOWER_UP;broadcast,multicast,up,running,lowerup> mtu 1500 arp 1 ethernet? init addrgenmode eui64 addr C8:F7:50:04:FF:DD driver e1000e rx:0,0 tx:0,0
<d> (enp0s31f6): queued link change for ifindex 2
<info> (enp0s31f6): carrier: link connected
<t> ethtool[2]: ETHTOOL_GSET, enp0s31f6: success
<d> (enp0s31f6): add_pending_action (2): 'queued-state-change-disconnected'
<d> (enp0s31f6): queue-state[disconnected, reason:carrier-changed, id:999]: queue state change
<d> (enp0s31f6): remove_pending_action (1): 'carrier-wait'
<d> properties-changed[X]: type NMDeviceEthernet, iface NMDBusDeviceEthernetSkeleton: {'AvailableConnections': <[objectpath '/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/1', '/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/2', '/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/3']>, 'Carrier': <true>}
<d> (enp0s31f6): queue-state[disconnected, reason:carrier-changed, id:999]: change state
<i> (enp0s31f6): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
<d> platform-linux: link: change 2: user-ipv6ll: set IPv6 address generation mode to none
<d> platform-linux: do-request-link: 2 
<t> platform-linux: event-notification: RTM_NEWLINK, flags 0, seq 0: 2: enp0s31f6 <UP,LOWER_UP;broadcast,multicast,up,running,lowerup> mtu 1500 arp 1 ethernet? not-init addrgenmode none addr C8:F7:50:04:FF:DD rx:0,0 tx:0,0
<d> platform: signal: link changed: 2: enp0s31f6 <UP,LOWER_UP;broadcast,multicast,up,running,lowerup> mtu 1500 arp 1 ethernet? init addrgenmode none addr C8:F7:50:04:FF:DD driver e1000e rx:0,0 tx:0,0
<d> (enp0s31f6): queued link change for ifindex 2
<t> platform-linux: event-notification: RTM_NEWLINK, flags 0, seq 82: 2: enp0s31f6 <UP,LOWER_UP;broadcast,multicast,up,running,lowerup> mtu 1500 arp 1 ethernet? not-init addrgenmode none addr C8:F7:50:04:FF:DD rx:0,0 tx:0,0
<d> platform-linux: do-change-link[2]: success changing link: success
<d> platform-linux: sysctl: setting '/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/enp0s31f6/disable_ipv6' to '0' (current value is '1')
<d> platform-linux: sysctl: setting '/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/enp0s31f6/accept_ra_defrtr' to '0' (current value is '1')
<d> platform-linux: sysctl: setting '/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/enp0s31f6/accept_ra_pinfo' to '0' (current value is '1')
<d> platform-linux: sysctl: setting '/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/enp0s31f6/accept_ra_rtr_pref' to '0' (current value is '1')
<d> platform-linux: sysctl: setting '/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/enp0s31f6/use_tempaddr' to '0' (current value is identical)
<d> platform-linux: sysctl: setting '/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/enp0s31f6/forwarding' to '0' (current value is identical)
<d> policy: re-enabling autoconnect for all connections on enp0s31f6
<d> (enp0s31f6): add_pending_action (2): 'autoactivate'
<d> (enp0s31f6): remove_pending_action (1): 'queued-state-change-disconnected'
<t> platform-linux: event-notification: RTM_NEWROUTE, flags create, seq 0: table 255 ff00::/8 via :: dev 2 metric 256 mss 0 rt-src rt-boot
<d> platform: signal: route   6   added: table 255 ff00::/8 via :: dev 2 metric 256 mss 0 rt-src rt-boot
<d> (enp0s31f6): queued IP6 config change
<d> properties-changed[X]: type NMDeviceEthernet, iface NMDBusDeviceEthernetSkeleton: {'State': <uint32 30>, 'StateReason': <(uint32 30, uint32 40)>}
<d> properties-changed[X]: type NMManager, iface NMDBusManagerSkeleton: {'ActiveConnections': <[objectpath '/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1']>}
<i> policy: auto-activating connection 'Wired connection 1'
<t> active-connection[X]: creating
<d> active-connection[X]: set device "enp0s31f6" [X]
<d> (enp0s31f6): add_pending_action (2): 'activation-0x55ab86b688a0'
<d> active-connection[X]: constructed (NMActRequest, version-id 4, type managed)
<d> (enp0s31f6): remove_pending_action (1): 'autoactivate'
<d> properties-changed[X]: type NMIP6Config, iface NMDBusIP6ConfigSkeleton: {'RouteData': <[{'dest': <'ff00::'>, 'prefix': <uint32 8>, 'metric': <uint32 256>, 'table': <uint32 255>}]>, 'Routes': <@a(ayuayu) []>}
<d> (enp0s31f6): ip4-config: update (commit=0, new-config=0x55ab86b651f0)
<d> manager: (enp0s31f6): assume: cannot generate connection: device has no existing configuration
<t> exported-object[X]: export: "/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/4"
<t> properties-changed[X]: ignoring notification for prop g-object-path on type NMActRequest
<t> properties-changed[X]: ignoring notification for prop path on type NMActRequest
<i> (enp0s31f6): Activation: starting connection 'Wired connection 1' (496467b0-8f31-3e42-abc2-6fb5da3e1df9)
<d> (enp0s31f6): activation-stage: schedule activate_stage1_device_prepare,v4 (id 1014)
<d> properties-changed[X]: type NMManager, iface NMDBusManagerSkeleton: {'ActiveConnections': <[objectpath '/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/4', '/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1']>}
<d> properties-changed[X]: type NMDeviceEthernet, iface NMDBusDeviceEthernetSkeleton: {'ActiveConnection': <objectpath '/'>}
<d> (enp0s31f6): activation-stage: invoke activate_stage1_device_prepare,v4 (id 1014)
<i> (enp0s31f6): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
<d> active-connection[X]: set state activating (was unknown)
<d> active-connection[X]: check-master-ready: not signalling (state activating, no master)
<t> manager: default-route-metric: ifindex 2 reserves metric 100 (aspired 100)
<t> ethtool[2]: ETHTOOL_GSET, enp0s31f6: success
<d> (enp0s31f6): set-link: link negotiation is already configured
<t> (enp0s31f6): set-hw-addr: setting MAC address to '70:5A:B6:AE:87:48' (set-cloned, 70:5A:B6:AE:87:48)...
<d> (enp0s31f6): taking down device 2
<d> platform: link: setting down "enp0s31f6" (2)
<d> platform-linux: link: change 2: flags: set 0x0/0x1 ([] / [up])
<d> platform-linux: do-request-link: 2 
<t> platform-linux: event-notification: RTM_NEWLINK, flags 0, seq 0: 2: enp0s31f6 <DOWN;broadcast,multicast> mtu 1500 arp 1 ethernet? not-init addrgenmode none addr C8:F7:50:04:FF:DD rx:0,0 tx:0,0
<d> platform: signal: link changed: 2: enp0s31f6 <DOWN;broadcast,multicast> mtu 1500 arp 1 ethernet? init addrgenmode none addr C8:F7:50:04:FF:DD driver e1000e rx:0,0 tx:0,0
<d> (enp0s31f6): queued link change for ifindex 2
<t> platform-linux: event-notification: RTM_DELROUTE, flags 0, seq 0: table 255 ff00::/8 via :: dev 2 metric 256 mss 0 rt-src rt-boot rtm_flags linkdown
<d> platform: signal: route   6 removed: table 255 ff00::/8 via :: dev 2 metric 256 mss 0 rt-src rt-boot
<d> (enp0s31f6): queued IP6 config change
<t> platform-linux: event-notification: RTM_NEWLINK, flags 0, seq 84: 2: enp0s31f6 <DOWN;broadcast,multicast> mtu 1500 arp 1 ethernet? not-init addrgenmode none addr C8:F7:50:04:FF:DD rx:0,0 tx:0,0
<t> platform-linux: event-notification: RTM_NEWROUTE, flags multi, seq 85, in-dump: 0.0.0.0/0 via 10.10.160.1 dev 3 metric 600 mss 0 rt-src rt-dhcp scope global
<t> platform-linux: event-notification: RTM_NEWROUTE, flags multi, seq 85, in-dump: 10.10.160.0/21 via 0.0.0.0 dev 3 metric 600 mss 0 rt-src rt-kernel scope link pref-src 10.10.160.183
<t> platform-linux: event-notification: RTM_NEWROUTE, flags multi, seq 85, in-dump: 169.254.0.0/16 via 0.0.0.0 dev 3 metric 1000 mss 0 rt-src rt-boot scope link
<t> platform-linux: event-notification: RTM_NEWROUTE, flags multi, seq 85: ignore
(x7)
<t> platform-linux: event-notification: RTM_NEWROUTE, flags multi, seq 86: ignore
<t> platform-linux: event-notification: RTM_NEWROUTE, flags multi, seq 86, in-dump: fe80::/64 via :: dev 3 metric 256 mss 0 rt-src rt-kernel
<t> platform-linux: event-notification: RTM_NEWROUTE, flags multi, seq 86, in-dump: fe80::/64 via :: dev 3 metric 600 mss 0 rt-src rt-kernel
<t> platform-linux: event-notification: RTM_NEWROUTE, flags multi, seq 86: ignore
(x2)
<t> platform-linux: event-notification: RTM_NEWROUTE, flags multi, seq 86, in-dump: table 255 ff00::/8 via :: dev 3 metric 256 mss 0 rt-src rt-boot
<d> platform-linux: do-change-link[2]: success changing link: success
<d> platform: link: setting "enp0s31f6" (2) hardware address
<d> platform-linux: link: change 2: address: 70:5A:B6:AE:87:48 (6 bytes)
<d> platform-linux: do-request-link: 2 
<t> platform-linux: event-notification: RTM_NEWLINK, flags 0, seq 0: 2: enp0s31f6 <DOWN;broadcast,multicast> mtu 1500 arp 1 ethernet? not-init addrgenmode none addr 70:5A:B6:AE:87:48 rx:0,0 tx:0,0
<d> platform: signal: link changed: 2: enp0s31f6 <DOWN;broadcast,multicast> mtu 1500 arp 1 ethernet? init addrgenmode none addr 70:5A:B6:AE:87:48 driver e1000e rx:0,0 tx:0,0
<t> platform-linux: event-notification: RTM_NEWLINK, flags 0, seq 88: 2: enp0s31f6 <DOWN;broadcast,multicast> mtu 1500 arp 1 ethernet? not-init addrgenmode none addr 70:5A:B6:AE:87:48 rx:0,0 tx:0,0
<d> platform-linux: do-change-link[2]: success changing link: success
<d> (enp0s31f6): hw-addr: hardware address now 70:5A:B6:AE:87:48
<i> (enp0s31f6): set-hw-addr: set-cloned MAC address to 70:5A:B6:AE:87:48 (70:5A:B6:AE:87:48)
<d> (enp0s31f6): bringing up device 2
<d> platform: link: setting up "enp0s31f6" (2)
<d> platform-linux: link: change 2: flags: set 0x1/0x1 ([up] / [up])
time 11:32:15
<d> platform-linux: do-request-link: 2 
<t> platform-linux: event-notification: RTM_NEWLINK, flags 0, seq 0: 2: enp0s31f6 <UP;broadcast,multicast,up,running> mtu 1500 arp 1 ethernet? not-init addrgenmode none addr 70:5A:B6:AE:87:48 rx:0,0 tx:0,0
<d> platform: signal: link changed: 2: enp0s31f6 <UP;broadcast,multicast,up,running> mtu 1500 arp 1 ethernet? init addrgenmode none addr 70:5A:B6:AE:87:48 driver e1000e rx:0,0 tx:0,0
<t> platform-linux: event-notification: RTM_NEWLINK, flags 0, seq 90: 2: enp0s31f6 <UP;broadcast,multicast,up,running> mtu 1500 arp 1 ethernet? not-init addrgenmode none addr 70:5A:B6:AE:87:48 rx:0,0 tx:0,0
<d> platform-linux: do-change-link[2]: success changing link: success
<d> (enp0s31f6): add_pending_action (2): 'carrier-wait'
<d> (enp0s31f6): carrier: link disconnected (deferring action for 6000 milli seconds) (id=1022)
<t> ethtool[2]: ETHTOOL_GLINK, enp0s31f6: success
<t> (enp0s31f6): add_pending_action (2): 'carrier-wait' already pending (expected)
<d> (enp0s31f6): activation-stage: schedule activate_stage2_device_config,v4 (id 1024)
<d> (enp0s31f6): activation-stage: complete activate_stage1_device_prepare,v4 (id 1014)
<d> properties-changed[X]: type NMDeviceEthernet, iface NMDBusDeviceEthernetSkeleton: {'ActiveConnection': <objectpath '/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/4'>, 'Carrier': <false>, 'HwAddress': <'70:5A:B6:AE:87:48'>, 'State': <uint32 40>, 'StateReason': <(uint32 40, uint32 0)>}
<d> properties-changed[X]: type NMManager, iface NMDBusManagerSkeleton: {'ActiveConnections': <[objectpath '/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/4', '/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1']>}
<d> properties-changed[X]: type NMActRequest, iface NMDBusActiveConnectionSkeleton: {'State': <uint32 1>}
<d> (enp0s31f6): activation-stage: invoke activate_stage2_device_config,v4 (id 1024)
<i> (enp0s31f6): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
<d> (enp0s31f6): bringing up device 2
<d> platform: link: setting up "enp0s31f6" (2)
<d> platform-linux: link: change 2: flags: set 0x1/0x1 ([up] / [up])
<d> platform-linux: do-request-link: 2 
<t> platform-linux: event-notification: RTM_NEWLINK, flags 0, seq 92: 2: enp0s31f6 <UP;broadcast,multicast,up,running> mtu 1500 arp 1 ethernet? not-init addrgenmode none addr 70:5A:B6:AE:87:48 rx:0,0 tx:0,0
<d> platform-linux: do-change-link[2]: success changing link: success
<t> ethtool[2]: ETHTOOL_GLINK, enp0s31f6: success
<t> (enp0s31f6): add_pending_action (2): 'carrier-wait' already pending (expected)
<d> (enp0s31f6): activation-stage: complete activate_stage2_device_config,v4 (id 1024)
<d> properties-changed[X]: type NMIP6Config, iface NMDBusIP6ConfigSkeleton: {'RouteData': <@aa{sv} []>, 'Routes': <@a(ayuayu) []>}
<d> properties-changed[X]: type NMDeviceEthernet, iface NMDBusDeviceEthernetSkeleton: {'State': <uint32 50>, 'StateReason': <(uint32 50, uint32 0)>}
<d> (enp0s31f6): activation-stage: schedule activate_stage3_ip_config_start,v4 (id 1032)
<d> (enp0s31f6): activation-stage: invoke activate_stage3_ip_config_start,v4 (id 1032)
<t> (enp0s31f6): ip4-state: set to 1 (wait)
<t> (enp0s31f6): ip6-state: set to 1 (wait)
<d> active-connection[X]: set state-flags layer2-ready (was none)
<i> (enp0s31f6): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
<t> (enp0s31f6): ip4-state: set to 2 (conf)
<t> exported-object[X]: export: "/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/DHCP4Config/4"
<t> properties-changed[X]: ignoring notification for prop path on type NMDhcp4Config
<t> properties-changed[X]: ignoring notification for prop g-object-path on type NMDhcp4Config
<t> (enp0s31f6): ipv4.route-table = 254 (policy routing not enabled)
<i> dhcp4 (enp0s31f6): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
<d> dhcp4 (enp0s31f6): creating composite dhclient config /var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient-enp0s31f6.conf
<d> dhcp4 (enp0s31f6): looking for existing config X
X
<d> dhcp4 (enp0s31f6): merging existing dhclient config /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf
<d> dhcp4 (enp0s31f6): running: /sbin/dhclient -d -q -sf /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper -pf /run/dhclient-enp0s31f6.pid -lf /var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient-496467b0-8f31-3e42-abc2-6fb5da3e1df9-enp0s31f6.lease -cf /var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient-enp0s31f6.conf enp0s31f6
<i> dhcp4 (enp0s31f6): dhclient started with pid 5232
<d> (enp0s31f6): add_pending_action (3): 'dhcp4'
<t> (enp0s31f6): ip6-state: set to 2 (conf)
<d> platform-linux: link: change 2: user-ipv6ll: set IPv6 address generation mode to eui64
<d> platform-linux: do-request-link: 2 
<t> platform-linux: event-notification: RTM_NEWLINK, flags 0, seq 0: 2: enp0s31f6 <UP;broadcast,multicast,up,running> mtu 1500 arp 1 ethernet? not-init addrgenmode eui64 addr 70:5A:B6:AE:87:48 rx:0,0 tx:0,0
<d> platform: signal: link changed: 2: enp0s31f6 <UP;broadcast,multicast,up,running> mtu 1500 arp 1 ethernet? init addrgenmode eui64 addr 70:5A:B6:AE:87:48 driver e1000e rx:0,0 tx:0,0
<d> (enp0s31f6): queued link change for ifindex 2
<t> platform-linux: event-notification: RTM_NEWLINK, flags 0, seq 94: 2: enp0s31f6 <UP;broadcast,multicast,up,running> mtu 1500 arp 1 ethernet? not-init addrgenmode eui64 addr 70:5A:B6:AE:87:48 rx:0,0 tx:0,0
<d> platform-linux: do-change-link[2]: success changing link: success
<d> platform-linux: sysctl: setting '/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/enp0s31f6/disable_ipv6' to '1' (current value is '0')
<d> platform-linux: sysctl: setting '/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/enp0s31f6/use_tempaddr' to '0' (current value is identical)
<d> platform-linux: sysctl: setting '/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/enp0s31f6/hop_limit' to '64' (current value is identical)
<d> platform-linux: sysctl: setting '/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/enp0s31f6/forwarding' to '0' (current value is identical)
<d> platform-linux: sysctl: setting '/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/enp0s31f6/accept_ra_defrtr' to '1' (current value is '0')
<d> platform-linux: sysctl: setting '/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/enp0s31f6/accept_ra' to '1' (current value is '0')
<d> platform-linux: sysctl: setting '/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/enp0s31f6/accept_ra_rtr_pref' to '1' (current value is '0')
<d> platform-linux: sysctl: setting '/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/enp0s31f6/accept_ra_pinfo' to '1' (current value is '0')
<d> platform-linux: sysctl: setting '/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/enp0s31f6/disable_ipv6' to '0' (current value is '1')
<t> (enp0s31f6): ip6-state: set to 3 (done)
<d> active-connection[X]: set state-flags layer2-ready,ip6-ready (was layer2-ready)
<d> (enp0s31f6): activation-stage: complete activate_stage3_ip_config_start,v4 (id 1032)
<d> properties-changed[X]: type NMActRequest, iface NMDBusActiveConnectionSkeleton: {'StateFlags': <uint32 20>}
<d> properties-changed[X]: type NMDeviceEthernet, iface NMDBusDeviceEthernetSkeleton: {'State': <uint32 70>, 'StateReason': <(uint32 70, uint32 0)>}
<d> bus-manager: (dhcp) accepted connection 0x55ab86aaea60 on private socket
<d> dhcp4 (enp0s31f6): unmapped DHCP state 'PREINIT'
<d> dhcp4 (enp0s31f6): DHCP reason 'PREINIT' -> state 'unknown'
<d> bus-manager: (dhcp) closed connection 0x55ab86aaea60 on private socket
<t> platform-linux: event-notification: RTM_NEWLINK, flags 0, seq 0: 2: enp0s31f6 <UP;broadcast,multicast,up> mtu 1500 arp 1 ethernet? not-init addrgenmode eui64 addr 70:5A:B6:AE:87:48 rx:0,0 tx:0,0
<d> platform: signal: link changed: 2: enp0s31f6 <UP;broadcast,multicast,up> mtu 1500 arp 1 ethernet? init addrgenmode eui64 addr 70:5A:B6:AE:87:48 driver e1000e rx:0,0 tx:0,0
<d> (enp0s31f6): queued link change for ifindex 2
time 11:32:18
<t> properties-changed[X]: ignoring notification for prop scanning on type NMDeviceWifi
time 11:32:19
<t> platform-linux: event-notification: RTM_NEWLINK, flags 0, seq 0: ignore
(x2)
<t> platform-linux: event-notification: RTM_NEWLINK, flags 0, seq 0: 3: wlp2s0 X
<d> platform: signal: link changed: 3: wlp2s0 X
<d> (wlp2s0): queued link change X
<t> platform-linux: event-notification: RTM_NEWROUTE, flags multi, seq 95, in-dump: 0.0.0.0/0 via 10.10.160.1 dev 3 metric 600 mss 0 rt-src rt-dhcp rtm_flags linkdown scope global
<d> platform: signal: route   4 changed: 0.0.0.0/0 via 10.10.160.1 dev 3 metric 600 mss 0 rt-src rt-dhcp rtm_flags linkdown scope global
<d> (wlp2s0): queued IP4 config change
<t> platform-linux: event-notification: RTM_NEWROUTE, flags multi, seq 95, in-dump: 10.10.160.0/21 via 0.0.0.0 dev 3 metric 600 mss 0 rt-src rt-kernel rtm_flags linkdown scope link pref-src 10.10.160.183
<d> platform: signal: route   4 changed: 10.10.160.0/21 via 0.0.0.0 dev 3 metric 600 mss 0 rt-src rt-kernel rtm_flags linkdown scope link pref-src 10.10.160.183
<t> platform-linux: event-notification: RTM_NEWROUTE, flags multi, seq 95, in-dump: 169.254.0.0/16 via 0.0.0.0 dev 3 metric 1000 mss 0 rt-src rt-boot rtm_flags linkdown scope link
<d> platform: signal: route   4 changed: 169.254.0.0/16 via 0.0.0.0 dev 3 metric 1000 mss 0 rt-src rt-boot rtm_flags linkdown scope link
<t> platform-linux: event-notification: RTM_NEWROUTE, flags multi, seq 95: ignore
(x4)
<t> platform-linux: event-notification: RTM_NEWROUTE, flags multi, seq 95: ignore
(x3)
<t> platform-linux: event-notification: RTM_NEWROUTE, flags multi, seq 96: ignore
<t> platform-linux: event-notification: RTM_NEWROUTE, flags multi, seq 96, in-dump: fe80::/64 via :: dev 3 metric 256 mss 0 rt-src rt-kernel rtm_flags linkdown
<d> platform: signal: route   6 changed: fe80::/64 via :: dev 3 metric 256 mss 0 rt-src rt-kernel rtm_flags linkdown
<d> (wlp2s0): queued IP6 config change
<t> platform-linux: event-notification: RTM_NEWROUTE, flags multi, seq 96, in-dump: fe80::/64 via :: dev 3 metric 600 mss 0 rt-src rt-kernel rtm_flags linkdown
<d> platform: signal: route   6 changed: fe80::/64 via :: dev 3 metric 600 mss 0 rt-src rt-kernel rtm_flags linkdown
<t> platform-linux: event-notification: RTM_NEWROUTE, flags multi, seq 96: ignore
(x2)
<t> platform-linux: event-notification: RTM_NEWROUTE, flags multi, seq 96, in-dump: table 255 ff00::/8 via :: dev 3 metric 256 mss 0 rt-src rt-boot rtm_flags linkdown
<d> platform: signal: route   6 changed: table 255 ff00::/8 via :: dev 3 metric 256 mss 0 rt-src rt-boot rtm_flags linkdown
<i> (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> authenticating
<t> properties-changed[X]: ignoring notification for prop scanning on type NMDeviceWifi
X
<d> (wlp2s0): ip4-config: X
<t> hostname: transient hostname retrieval failed
(x2)
<d> properties-changed[X]: type NMDeviceWifi, X
X
<d> properties-changed[X]: type NMWifiAP, X
XXXXX
<i> (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: X
<t> platform-linux: event-notification: RTM_NEWLINK, flags 0, seq 0: ignore
(x2)
<t> platform-linux: event-notification: RTM_NEWLINK, flags 0, seq 0: 3: wlp2s0 X
<d> platform: signal: link changed: 3: wlp2s0 X
<d> (wlp2s0): queued link change X
<i> (wlp2s0): X
X
<t> platform-linux: event-notification: RTM_NEWLINK, flags 0, seq 0: 3: wlp2s0 X
<d> platform: signal: link changed: 3: wlp2s0 X
<d> (wlp2s0): queued link change X
<d> properties-changed[X]: type NMDeviceWifi, X
<i> (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: X
<d> properties-changed[X]: type NMDeviceWifi, X
<d> properties-changed[X]: type NMWifiAP, X
=== Around this time the nm-applet icon is back to the Wifi signal strength
time 11:32:20
<d> (wlp2s0): activation-stage: X
XXX
time 11:32:21
<d> (enp0s31f6): carrier: link disconnected (calling deferred action) (id=1022)
<d> (enp0s31f6): add_pending_action (4): 'queued-state-change-unavailable'
<d> (enp0s31f6): queue-state[unavailable, reason:carrier-changed, id:1153]: queue state change
<d> properties-changed[X]: type NMDeviceEthernet, iface NMDBusDeviceEthernetSkeleton: {'AvailableConnections': <[objectpath '/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/2']>}
<d> (enp0s31f6): queue-state[unavailable, reason:carrier-changed, id:1153]: change state
<i> (enp0s31f6): state change: ip-config -> unavailable (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
<d> (enp0s31f6): deactivating device (reason 'carrier-changed') [40]
<t> manager: default-route-metric: ifindex 2 released
...
```

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I'm sorry I don't understand your question :-) What directive? What do you refer to by "it"? enp0s31f6 is a wired LAN interface (is it unclear from my description?) Thank you!

Comment: Nevermind, somewhat the "Cloned" part escaped me.

Comment: For some reason, activation fails because carries is lost. Either because of driver, network card, or switch. You could configure main.ignore-carrier (see man NetworkManager.conf). Though, that is merely a workaround with other problems. I'd enable level=TRACE logging an look at the log

Comment: @thaller could you have a look at it? I can't make sense of all this.